# Before filter in Sinatra causing a redirect loop

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have this simple code:

```
require 'sinatra'

before  do
  redirect '/login'
end

get '/login' do
  'hello'
end

get '/test' do
  'should not show'
end
```

This simple app is supposed to redirect every route, including `/test` to the `login` route. Instead, I'm getting a redirect loop.

I use the latest version of Sinatra 2.0.5.

Comment: For 'login' route you have redirect to 'login', it follows redirect and redirects again.

Comment: @Vasilisa what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to exclude `/login` route from before_filter

```
before do
  redirect '/login' if request.path_info != "/login"
end
```

Comment: Oh wow this works. I didn't realize the whole workflow. So basically, when I go to "/test", the "before" filter executes, and redirects me to "login"...then, the before filter is executed AGAIN (the part I overlooked). Gotcha, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what I meant in the comment :) Great, that you've figured it out! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

A solution is offered above but the explanation is that `redirect` triggers *browser* redirect so the process will begin again at the start every time. To use a server side redirect use `call`. From [the docs](http://sinatrarb.com/intro.html):

> Triggering Another Route
>
> Sometimes pass is not what you want, instead you would like to get the
>   result of calling another route. Simply use call to achieve this:

```
get '/foo' do
  status, headers, body = call env.merge("PATH_INFO" => '/bar')
  [status, headers, body.map(&:upcase)]
end

get '/bar' do
  "bar"
end
```

> Note that in the example above, you would ease testing and increase
>   performance by simply moving "bar" into a helper used by both /foo and
>   /bar.
>
> If you want the request to be sent to the same application instance
>   rather than a duplicate, use call! instead of call.
>
> Check out the Rack specification if you want to learn more about call.

Hence, you probably want a helper (or more likely, a *condition*, if you're checking for auth).